# How to send char* of length N using amqp C library?

Tags: c, rabbitmq, amqp

How to send `char*` of length `N` over [amqp (RabbitMQ) C library](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c)?
In all samples they use something like `amqp_basic_cstring(char*)` while I have not null terminated stinge but a pair `char *` and its `length`?

Comment: Where is `amqp_basic_cstring` defined ? what does it do ?

Answer (score 1):

All C strings are terminated by the special character `'\0'`. If your `N` is less than the length of the string, you could make a copy and then terminate it at position `N` and send it as a normal C string.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `amqp_basic_cstring()` in the API, I think you mean `amqp_cstring_bytes()` which wraps a C-string in an `amqp_t` structure, you have to null-terminate the string when using this function because it uses `strlen()` internally to count the string, so allocate an extra byte and null-terminate the string.

```
str[len-1]='\0';
```

The other option is to wrap the C-string in an `amqp_byte_t` yourself, I don't think you should do that, anyway:

```
amqp_bytes_t str;
str.len = length; //string length
str.bytes = cptr; //pointer to string

foo(..., str, ...);
```